# How to rename a database in Web SQL?

Tags: sql, database, rename, web-sql

Is there a way to rename a database in Web SQL? 
I need a simple way to backup all data to another Web SQL database.

Comment: Why not just use the backup command?

Comment: Is there such thing? I can't find it.

Comment: A quick search found this: [link](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/02/24/Creating-a-data-backup-of-a-WebSQL-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is no native way to do this. So the best answer should be: `select * from ...` each table you want to backup and iterate through results while inserting this data into new "backup" database. 
So there is no simpler way as `rename` or `backup`.

Thank you @Chuck